# How to fetch data from API in Node.js to a view in React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sql-server, api, rest

I tried to get data from my SQL Server Management Studio. I already made the the query inside API, so when I access those links using postman, it will retrieve data equals to the query inside those links. But when i want to show the data at page, it not comes out even though it already comes out at the console log. The error always changing, but never solved.

**DbOperations Query**

```
const config = require('./dbConfig');
const sql = require('mssql');
```

```
    async function getRoles() {
          try {
              let pool = await sql.connect(/My Configuration Database/);
              let products = await pool.request().query("SELECT [id],[division] FROM [FMLX_IME].[dbo].[ime.tbl_roles]");
              return products.recordsets;
              }
          catch(error) {
               console.log(error);
              }
          }
```

**This is how I insert the function to API links**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('bodyParser');
const Db = require('./dbOperations');
const router = express.Router();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api', router);
```

```
router.use((request, response, next) => {
     console.log("============ MIDDLEWARE ============");
     next();
});

router.route('/get-roles').get((request, response) => {
    Db.getRoles().then(result => {
        response.json(result);
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

**This how I tried to fetch the data, already tried so many ways but nothing works. Only success to retrieved the data if using API that already online or running, not from my localhost. (Already tried using axios too)**

```
Class ManualTest extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           roles: [],
           isLoaded: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/get-roles')
           .then(result => console.log(result.json()))
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    roles: json,
                    isLoaded: true
                })
            }).catch((err) => {
                 console.log(err);   
            });
    }

    render() {

      const { isLoaded, roles } = this.state;

      if(!isLoaded)
         return <div>Loading...</div>

         return (
            <div className="App">
                 <ul>
                     {roles.map(role => (
                        <li key={role.id}>
                            ID: {role.id} || ROLE: {role.role}
                        </li>
                      ))}
                 </ul>
            </div>
         );
    }
}

export default ManualTest
```

Comment: data never show, even though the console log retrieve it. I already tried using another free to use API from google for testing purpose and it works. But using my own localhost API thats never happened.

Comment: Please help, this is my internship project and I made a minor progress at this project, because I cant work the other stuff if this still not works.

Comment: put console log after `fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/get-roles')
` see if data is coming you are not logging there

Comment: yes, the data come and appear as json at console log. I am add ```.then(result => console.log(result.json())) ``` after ***fetch*** @AshishKamble

Comment: but still it wont appear if I am insert it at the view page element inside ```<div></div>``` @AshishKamble

Comment: I am tried adding few different console log to track the problem, ```.then(result => console.log(result)))``` ***to check if there is problem with connection and there's none***

Comment: so, I am added another different approach console log ```.then(console.log(res)))``` ***I got an error says "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."***, are this one start to getting closer?

Comment: your code looks good to me, logged data is array or json, you set state as array na

Comment: `cont { isLoaded, roles } = this.state;` must be `const`

Comment: i am sorry, i got miss typing here. The actual code not typo at all. And yes this very confusing for me, almost take weeks for this problem only. @AshishKamble